# Setting shell path for atom editor

Tags: bash, atom-editor, fish

I use the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com), which isn't compatible with `rbenv`, and atom is throwing an error saying that it can't find `ruby` (rightfully so).

Is there a way I could tell atom to use a particular file path for the shell, other than the one set as the default from `chsh`? Ideally, I would just set it to `/bin/bash`, and continue using fish outside of atom.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? BTW I don't use `rbenv`, but `rbenv` [appears to support the Fish shell](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/blob/master/completions/rbenv.fish), it may be something else though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that Atom isn't able to use the correct PATH variable. The same problem appears to exist for zsh, and here's a gist that describes a solution that's worked for me:

https://gist.github.com/dustinblackman/db56445e5d649ccbd2b2

I believe you should be able to modify it to work for fish as well. At a minimum, you could create a file with a bash style PATH referencing the rbenv paths you need, and then point the above to that file instead of .zshrc.